# displaying the amount of root processes using script

Tags: bash, process, root

i need to display a count of root processes when rootjob is on command line
i have tried......

```
case $arg in
  rootjobs)
    echo "Root is running $(pgrep -s root %R) processes"
    ;;
```

also tried

```
case $arg in
  rootjobs)
    echo "Root is running $(pgrep -u root| wc) processes"
    ;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps:

> To see every process running as root (real & effective ID) in user
>   format: ps -U root -u root u

so does

> ps -U root -u root u | wc -l

do what you want? I am running on Ubuntu 14.04.1, other systems might need a different command.